# Octave precision for floats: Is it 128 bit under the hood?

Tags: c#, signal-processing, octave

I'm making a C# version of the Burg algorithm using an approach presented by Koen Vos in "A Fast Implementation of Burg’s Method".

I used the GNU Octave `arburg` function to compare the results with.
The test results are almost the same when I use `decimal` for internal variables in my C# code (accuracy is 0.0000000000001) but quite different when I use `double` (accuracy is 0.01).

As I know [GNU Octave uses 64-bit precision for floats](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Numeric-Data-Types.html#Numeric-Data-Types), not 128-bit. Am I wrong?

```
/* Coefficients for comparision are taken from GNU Octave arburg() 
* t = [0:2000];
* x = sin( 2 * pi() * t / (512 / 5.2));
* output_precision(16)
* [a, v, k] = arburg(x(1:512), 4)
*/
```

The C# code is more than 300 lines so I think it's better to not put it here.

I think either GNU Octave uses 128-bit precision under the hood or I have a mistake in my C# code and increasing the precision of calculations mitigates this mistake somehow.

The question is it possible that float data in GNU Octave (or Matlab) are 128-bit inside?

Comment: It is a good idea if you compare your result with that of published in the paper.

Comment: There are some things in the paper that can be interpreted in more than one way. I wonder if you are familiar with the paper?

Comment: No, I don't. I mean that the results published in the paper are more reliable than results you would get by software implementations like octave or any other tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Octave uses 64-bit floats by default, there is no way to force it to use a higher precision. It knows only `double` (64-bit floats) and `single` (32-bit floats).

Intel (and compatible) processors can do computation with 80-bit floats (in C this is `long double`), but they don't support 128-bit floats. Some software might emulate 128-bit float for improved precision, but Octave is not one of them (nor is MATLAB).

Comment: C# decimal is a 128-bit float as I know. Though, it is not supported by hardware I think.

Comment: Relevant: [Wikipedia: Quadruple-precision floating point implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Implementations).  There are some hardware implementations, but mostly its handled in software.

Comment: **Fortran** uses *quadruple* precision floats (emulated since they not supported by FPU) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Except to symbolic vpa.

Comment: @rahnema1: Sure, and there are other packages that simulate higher precision, but these are not built-in types. `vpa` returns an object of class `sym`, not a built-in type. Octave itself does not know these types. I think OP would have known if their code used `vpa`.

Comment: There is a wrapped Version of the GCC float128 implementation that you can dllimport to c# floating around...